# How to exchange instantiated tilesprefabs from deactivated tiles to activetiles?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

Hi everyone I have been making and experimenting on an 3d endless runner game and came with an issue. Here is what I meant to achieve. I have two list of gameobjects called activeTiles and deactivatedTiles. According to my idea I want to first add all the prefab tiles to the deactivatedtTiles list. Next I have a `float amtTileOnScreen` variable which controls the amount of tiles put in front of the player to run. Then I take a random Tile from the list of deactivated tiles to activated tiles by considering the amount of tiles o screen and put in-front of the player. Used tiles are put back to deactivated tile list and the whole cycle begins.

The question is how do I achieve this? Help would be appreciated.

Here's what I have tried.

```
public class TileManager : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject[] tilePrefabs;

    private Transform playerTransform;
    private float spawnZ = -12f;
    private float tileLength = 24.0f;
    private int amtOfTilesOnScreen = 5;
    private float safeZone = 56.0f;
    private GameObject spawnedTile;



    public static List<GameObject> activeTiles;
    public static List<GameObject> deactivatedTiles;
    private int lastPrefabIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 transformTiles;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

        activeTiles = new List<GameObject>();
        deactivatedTiles = new List<GameObject>();
        playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

        for (int i = 0; i < amtOfTilesOnScreen; i++)
        {

            if (i < 1)
            {
                activeTiles.Add(SpawnTileAtFront(0));
            }
            else
            {
                activeTiles.Add(SpawnTileAtFront());
            }
        }


    }

    void Update () 
    {    
        if (playerTransform.position.z - safeZone > (spawnZ - amtOfTilesOnScreen * tileLength))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tilePrefabs.Length; i++)
            {
                spawnedTile = SpawnTileAtFront();
                deactivatedTiles.Add(spawnedTile);
                Debug.Log(deactivatedTiles.Count);
            }
            if (activeTiles.Count < (amtOfTilesOnScreen + 1))
            {
                activeTiles.Add(GetRandomDeactivatedTile());
                MoveTileToTheFront(GetRandomDeactivatedTile());
            }
            else
            {
                var disposeTile = activeTiles[0];
                deactivatedTiles.Add(disposeTile);
                DisposeActiveTiles(0);
            }

        }

    }

    private void MoveTileToTheFront(GameObject tile)
    {
        tile.transform.position = Vector3.forward * spawnZ;
        spawnZ += tileLength;
    }

    private GameObject SpawnTileAtFront(int prefabIndex = -1)
    {
        GameObject go;
        if (prefabIndex == -1)
        {
            go = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[RandomPrefabIndex()]) as GameObject;
        }
        else
        {
            go = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[prefabIndex]) as GameObject;
        }

        go.transform.SetParent(transform);
        MoveTileToTheFront(go);
        return go;
    }

    private void DisposeActiveTiles(int index)
    {
        GameObject unusedTile = activeTiles[index];
        activeTiles.RemoveAt(index);
        deactivatedTiles.Add(unusedTile);
    }

    private GameObject GetRandomDeactivatedTile()
    {
        if (deactivatedTiles.Count == 0)
            return null;
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, deactivatedTiles.Count);
        GameObject unusedTile = deactivatedTiles[randomIndex];
        deactivatedTiles.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
        return unusedTile;
    }

    private int RandomPrefabIndex()
    {
        if (tilePrefabs.Length <= 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int randomIndex = lastPrefabIndex;
        while (randomIndex == lastPrefabIndex)
        {
            randomIndex = Random.Range(0, tilePrefabs.Length);
        }
        lastPrefabIndex = randomIndex;
        return lastPrefabIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What is not working that you expected to work?

Comment: @EmreE for some reason Tiles are activated more than the specified in the `amtOfTileOnScreen` variable and at start if I pause 5 tiles are instantiated as requested and after another 5 tilesets are added. Then altogether there are 10 tiles but the after the 9th tile there's a huge gap before 10th tile. Also tiles won't get removed from behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Update () 
{    
    while (playerTransform.position.z - safeZone > (spawnZ - amtOfTilesOnScreen * tileLength))
    {
        // we need to add a new tile in front of the player
        GameObject t;

        if (deactivatedTiles.Count == 0) {
            // no deactivated tiles so we need to instantiate a new tile
            t = SpawnTileAtFront ();
        } else {
            // otherwise take deactivated tile into use
            t = GetRandomDeactivatedTile ();
            MoveTileToTheFront (t);
        }
        // new tile is now active tile
        activeTiles.Add (t);

        // take oldest active tile and move it to deactivated list
        DisposeActiveTiles(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mikki Koivisto.